# How to go from .srt subtitles and a .ts video to a .ts video with dvb_subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get from a .srt subtitle file + a .ts video file => a .ts video file with a dvb_subtitle.

My .srt:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel hendrerit massa.

2
00:00:05,000 --> 00:00:10,000
Aliquam dolor sapien, molestie ac sagittis eu, tempus nec est.

3
00:00:10,000 --> 00:00:28,000
Morbi id sem eu sapien consectetur imperdiet. Morbi sed purus et sapien interdum placerat vitae quis orci.
```

My .ts: sample_1920x1080.ts from https://filesamples.com/formats/ts

[SubtitleEdit](https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) command: `.\SubtitleEdit.exe /convert 'test_subtitles.srt' Blu-raysup /resolution:1920x1080 /overwrite`.
This creates a test_subtitles.sup file as expected.

I then use `ffmpeg` to include the .sup subtitles, like this: `.\ffmpeg.exe -y -i 'sample_1920x1080.ts' -fix_sub_duration -i 'test_subtitles.sup' -map 0:v -map 1:s -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec dvbsub -copyts -muxdelay 0 -max_delay 0 'output.ts'`. This works, but the results are sometimes not very readable. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of VLC showing that the subtitles are hard to read]

Do I have any other options here? Or options within subtitleedit/ffmpeg to f.ex. make the subtitles be bigger?

(I've posted this to the SubtitleEdit Github repository as well: https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/issues/4539.)

UPDATE:

I learned from the author of SubtitleEdit that it's indeed possible to increase the font size if using the graphical user interface of SubtitleEdit (see [here](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/issues/4539#issuecomment-734986814). However, I wish to do this using a command line tool.

Comment: hi buddy, whats the problem with srt file? you can embed them since into ts file as well as sup?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I follow you, @Abilogos. I need to add bitmap subtitles to the video, and I need the subtitles to be bigger then what I'm able to create with the commands in my question. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: i have updated my answer to include font-size, you can hardcode subtitle into video using this option with desired font size

Comment: do you know any online tools to convert srt to sub?

Comment: Googling "srt to sub" will show you that there are many such tools. "srt to sup" (sup is an image format) however does not yield many results.

Comment: i couldnt find any online solution, and the programs i have found were for MS Windows which i dont have

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 19.12.2020:

The idea from my last comment - a Python script that replaces the font size in Settings.xml of SubtitleEdit, to be called before your scripts:

https://github.com/Twenkid/Python-Various/blob/main/Exercise/SubtitleEdit/sub.py

```
python sub.py C:\SE3518\Settings.xml 44
```

etc.

...

Have you tried to scale the dvb track? That thread suggests it is possible:
[ffmpeg and dvb subtitles scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103786/ffmpeg-and-dvb-subtitles-scaling)

That part by Maknol (<strike>I haven't tried it though</strike>):

> -filter_complex "[0:s:0] scale=-1:2400 [sub],[0:v][sub] overlay=x=150:y=-80"
>
> where:
>
> scale - size of subtitle
>
> overlay x= - vertical
>
> overlay y= - horizontal

EDIT: I managed to scale the .sup subtitles with ffmpeg, but so far it worked in two passes, see below.

My sequence was:

1. Your command, producing a stream with the subtitles:

ffmpeg -i sample_1920x1080.ts -fix_sub_duration -i test_subtitles.sup -map 0:v -map 1:s -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec dvbsub -copyts -muxdelay 0 -max_delay 0 outputA.ts

2. Scale the subtitles and adjust their position (however it requires reencoding due to the filter_complex)

ffmpeg -i outputA.ts  -metadata title="Scale" -filter_complex "[0:s:0] scale=-1:1400 [sub],[0:v][sub] overlay=x=-250:y=-300" -c:v libx264 -b:v 5M -preset fast -aspect 16:9 -c:a copy output_Scaled.ts

Initial size:

[image]

My initial subtitles were bigger (font size 25) and the scaling coefficient here is small = 1400/1080

Scaled:

[image]

...

If I tried to do it in one pass, my syntax rendered the default size + overlayed the scaled ones (and displays only one item, not all).

That's the attempt for one pass:

#At once  overlays them ...
ffmpeg -i sample_1920x1080.ts  -fix_sub_duration -i test_subtitles.sup -scodec dvbsub -map 0:v -map 1:s -metadata title="Scale" -filter_complex "[1:s] scale=-1:1400 [sub],[0:v][sub] overlay=x=-250:y=-300" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast -aspect 16:9 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k outputSTACK_SUP.ts

It produces something like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I tried running your second command (see the result of the command here: https://pastebin.com/dLpiXiM7) but the resulting .ts file does not have a subtitle track. An excerpt from the ffmpeg output is "Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input". Are you able to see what I did wrong there?

Comment: Just commenting to let you know that I intent to offer a new bounty if the current one expires.

Comment: OK. What about the first command? Did you run it first; does otuputA have subtitles? (I play them with ffplay). Also, I had to mention that I generated the sup file using the GUI of Subtitle editor (the cmd line didn't work on my setup, it didn't produce a file and didn't find out why, no error message).

If you wish check my output files and the sup from the GUI:
http://twenkid.com/video/stack

Comment: Thanks again for responding. The first command works. That produces a video with one video track and one dvb_subtitle track. What I see from your "output_Scaled.ts" file is that there's not separate dvb_subtitle track. It looks like the subtitles are burned into the video, which is not what I want.

Comment: OK, I thought about is it possible to scale just the subtitle track, save it separately and then reinclude it. The best so far is:
ffmpeg -canvas_size 1920x1080 -i outputA.ts -filter_complex "[0:s:0] scale=-1:1800 [sub],[0:s:0][sub] overlay=x=-500:y=-400" -map 0:s -c:s dvdsub sub2X.mkv
The subtitles start from time 0 in the output.

Then - injecting the dvb track into the first video, but I don't know the right way for that yet.

See: sub2X.mkv in the linked dir +

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818276/in-ffmpeg-how-do-i-scale-dvdsub-subtitles-to-match-video-size-using-scale2ref

Comment: I found the setting in SubEdit, in Settings.xml
    <ExportBluRayFontName>Arial</ExportBluRayFontName>
    <ExportBluRayFontSize>40</ExportBluRayFontSize>
When changing here, it changes on the following "clean" opening (not reloading unsaved project), a cmd line call cleans it as well. (However on my machine it doesn't produce a .sup :), just prints: Subtitle Edit 3.5.18 - Batch converter and no errors)

So the "0-th" script would be to locate and update these lines (or only the size) with a simple substite parser/regex or xml parser, then call SubtitleEdit etc. in your initial sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it had to be done with ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i ./sample_1280x720.ts -i ./sample.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s dvd_subtitle ./out.ts
```

but ffmpeg wont accept it with this error:

> Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap
> to bitmap

`.srt` format is text based and `.sup` format is image based.

so as long as ffmpeg **refuses** to encode subtitle into video.

we can using `-vf` (video filter), **Hardcoding (srt) subtitle** into video:

```
ffmpeg -i ./sample_1280x720.ts -vf subtitles=sample.srt:force_style='Fontsize=24' ./out.ts
```

We Can define font size with `Fontsize` option.

[image]

but if have the `sup` and want to burn into video, you may use this:

```
ffmpeg -i ./sample_1280x720.ts -i ./sample.sup  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:s]overlay" ./out.ts
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however I do not wish to burn the subtitles into the video. I wish to have them as dvb_subtitles that can be enabled or disabled as the viewer pleases. By burning the subtitles into the video you can't disable them.

Comment: i have tried to find out a way to encoding srt to sup. unfortunately ffmpeg is not gonna do that. and you have to try your chance on other software like handbrake or subtitleEdit ... .

Comment: Thanks! I did find that it was possible to do with SubtitleEdit, and I do believe that there are other GUI options out there, but I'll continue my search for a command line tool that can do the job.